# PowerDNS replication sometimes don't work?

Tags: dns, powerdns

I have question about PowerDNS Authoritative server.
I have four DNS server with installed PowerDNS Authoritative server from scratch on four location. They work with MySQL in backend.
Problem is:

1. When I add new zone or update existing zone all propagate OK, without error, but if I test incident and stoping service on one DNS, later when I starting up service, zone which I add in meanwhile don't propagate. Where is problem ?
2. If I decide to add new DNS server no one zone is not propagated. How can I resolve this problem?

General question, what is advantage of powerDNS if he can't automatically update zone after some disaster or connectivity problem?

Comment: PowerDNS most definitely can update zones after outages. There must be something wrong with your setup. However, you have given almost zero details - please show configuration, database contents, logfiles around the problem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I created database by pdns docs.

database name `powerdns`.

```
CREATE TABLE domains (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name                  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  master                VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_check            INT DEFAULT NULL,
  type                  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  notified_serial       INT DEFAULT NULL,
  account               VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_index ON domains(name);


CREATE TABLE records (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain_id             INT DEFAULT NULL,
  name                  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  type                  VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  content               VARCHAR(64000) DEFAULT NULL,
  ttl                   INT DEFAULT NULL,
  prio                  INT DEFAULT NULL,
  change_date           INT DEFAULT NULL,
  disabled              TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
  ordername             VARCHAR(255) BINARY DEFAULT NULL,
  auth                  TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX nametype_index ON records(name,type);
CREATE INDEX domain_id ON records(domain_id);
CREATE INDEX recordorder ON records (domain_id, ordername);


CREATE TABLE supermasters (
  ip                    VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  nameserver            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  account               VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ip, nameserver)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE comments (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain_id             INT NOT NULL,
  name                  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  type                  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  modified_at           INT NOT NULL,
  account               VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  comment               VARCHAR(64000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX comments_domain_id_idx ON comments (domain_id);
CREATE INDEX comments_name_type_idx ON comments (name, type);
CREATE INDEX comments_order_idx ON comments (domain_id, modified_at);


CREATE TABLE domainmetadata (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain_id             INT NOT NULL,
  kind                  VARCHAR(32),
  content               TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX domainmetadata_idx ON domainmetadata (domain_id, kind);


CREATE TABLE cryptokeys (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain_id             INT NOT NULL,
  flags                 INT NOT NULL,
  active                BOOL,
  content               TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX domainidindex ON cryptokeys(domain_id);

CREATE TABLE tsigkeys (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name                  VARCHAR(255),
  algorithm             VARCHAR(50),
  secret                VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX namealgoindex ON tsigkeys(name, algorithm);
```

I created user and give all permision to database.

I put value into supermaster `('IP master", 'ns.slave', 'admin');`

Configuration file of master server:

```
launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=localhost
gmysql-user=powerdns_user
gmysql-dbname=powerdns
gmysql-password=password

allow-recursion=0.0.0.0/0
allow-axfr-ips=IP_address_slave1/32
allow-axfr-ips=IP_address_slave2/32
allow-axfr-ips=IP_address_slave3/32
config-dir=/etc/powerdns
daemon=yes
disable-axfr=no
guardian=yes
local-address=0.0.0.0
local-port=53
log-dns-details=on
loglevel=7
module-dir=/usr/lib/powerdns
master=yes
slave=no
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
socket-dir=/var/run
version-string=powerdns
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/pdns.d
```

Configuration file of slave:

```
launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=localhost
gmysql-dbname=powerdns
gmysql-user=powerdns_user
gmysql-password=password

allow-recursion=0.0.0.0/0
config-dir=/etc/powerdns
daemon=yes
disable-axfr=yes
guardian=yes
local-address=0.0.0.0
local-port=53
log-dns-details=on
loglevel=7
module-dir=/usr/lib/powerdns
master=no
slave=yes
slave-cycle-interval=60
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
socket-dir=/var/run
version-string=powerdns
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/pdns.d
```

When I add zone in master I see in log, all propagation is ok and that's correct. But if I stop service on one of slave server and add zone, I see in log propagation on all active slaves. When I start pdns after few minutes on testing (stopping pdns) slaves nothing happend. Don't have notify in log for that zone.

Comment: Maybe, lightweight question. :) How can I start manual replication ? Does enyone know ?